# String issue with assert on erase

Tags: c++

I am developing a program in C++, using the string container , as in std::string to store network data from the socket (this is peachy), I receive the data in a maximum possible 1452 byte frame at a time, the protocol uses a header that contains information about the data area portion of the packets length, and header is a fixed 20 byte length. My problem is that a string is giving me an unknown debug assertion, as in , it asserts , but I get NO message about the string. Now considering I can receive more than a single packet in a frame at a any time, I place all received data into the string , reinterpret_cast to my data struct, calculate the total length of the packet, then copy the data portion of the packet into a string for regex processing, At this point i do a string.erase, as in mybuff.Erase(totalPackLen); <~ THIS is whats calling the assert, but totalpacklen is less than the strings size.

Is there some convention I am missing here? Or is it that the std::string really is an inappropriate choice here? Ty.

Fixed it on my own. Rolled my own VERY simple buffer with a few C calls :)

```
int ret = recv(socket,m_buff,0);
if(ret > 0)
{
    BigBuff.append(m_buff,ret);

    while(BigBuff.size() > 16){
        Header *hdr = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(&BigBuff[0]);
        if(ntohs(hdr->PackLen) <= BigBuff.size() - 20){
            hdr->PackLen = ntohs(hdr->PackLen);
            string lData;
            lData.append(BigBuff.begin() + 20,BigBuff.begin() + 20 + hdr->PackLen);
            Parse(lData); //regex parsing helper function
            BigBuff.erase(hdr->PackLen + 20); //assert here when len is packlen is 235 and string len is 1458;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: images show whats going on, and sorry for the C style casts

Comment: *Code* would be much more helpful than screenshots from Visual Studio. Also, if your data contains `\000`, then `std::vector<char>` may be a more appropriate container for it.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot (which isn't very useful), please post complete, concise [sample code](http://sscce.org/) and a stack dump. For more guidelines, read ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: indeed the data does contain 0x00.

Comment: Ok, gratefull for the comments, If ya want a stack dump i'll post one. The images are to clarify the TEXT.

Comment: I'm suspicious about the `reinterpret_cast<type>(value)`; that tells the compiler "believe me, I know exactly what I'm doing".  Are you sure that you know enough to tell the compiler that?

Comment: Can `hdr->PackLen + 20` be less than 0?

Comment: No, header is a 20 byte data struct, consisting of in this order 1 long, 4 shorts, and 2 longs, all unsigned. EVERY packet sent to me has this header struct. it's part of the protocol. As far as me knowing to tell the compiler that, yes Im sure i want to byte align the data thats in the strings internal pointer to the struct.

Comment: (1) You realize that `BigBuff.erase(n)` erases everything starting at byte n through the end of the string?  (Not the cause of the assert, of course...)  (2) I agree `vector<char>` is a better container for this purpose  (3) This smells like memory corruption.  How is m_buff declared?

Comment: m_buff is declared as a char array. BigBuff.erase(n) erases from 0 to n. N being in this case way smaller than the actual contents of BigBuff.

Comment: std::string.erase has an optional 1st parameter for the start of the erase, if it's not supplied the start of the erase is at index position 0.

Comment: on that note it's also overloaded to take std::string::iterator as well.

Comment: char m_buff[1452]; // in class definition.

Comment: @johnathon - "std::string.erase has an optional 1st parameter for the start of the erase, if it's not supplied the start of the erase is at index position 0" - WRONG. If you supply only one parameter - it's the FIRST, not the second. You're giving the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment doesn't make sense:

```
    BigBuff.erase(hdr->PackLen + 20); //assert here when len is packlen is 235 and string len is 1458;
```

`BigBuff.erase(hdr->PackLen + 20)` will erase from `hdr->PackLen + 20` onwards till the end of the string. From the description of the code - seems to me that you're erasing **beyond** the end of the content data. [Here's the reference for `std::string::erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) for you.

Needless to say that `std::string` is entirely inappropriate here, it should be `std::vector`.

Comment: Might have been. Dumped it though. STL containers have their place, this application is not one of them.

Comment: Ya know. I'll plus ya , You may passing through, but at least your the only person that even tried to help beyond making assumptions about the purpose of the code and if i knew was i was doing in regions other than where it really was. As far as data serialization goes i can do it in my sleep. counting bytes yadda yadda, STL .. special containers that "act" like their raw data counterparts... not so much :))

Answer (score 2):

From the code snippet you provided it appears that your packet comprises a fixed-length binary header followed by a variable length ASCII string as a payload. Your first mistake is here:

```
BigBuff.append(m_buff,ret);
```

There are at least two problems here:
 1. Why the append? You presumably have dispatched with any previous messages. You should be starting with a clean slate.
 2. Mixing binary and string data can work, but more often than not it doesn't. It is usually better to keep the binary and ASCII data separate. Don't use std::string for non-string data.

Append adds data to the end of the string. The very next statement after the append is a test for a length of 16, which says to me that you should have started fresh. In the same vein you do that reinterpret cast from BigBuff[0]:

```
Header *hdr = reinterpret_cast<Header*>(&BigBuff[0]);
```

Because of your use of append, you are perpetually dealing with the header from the first packet received rather than the current packet. Finally, there's that erase:

```
BigBuff.erase(hdr->PackLen + 20);
```

Many problems here:
 - If the packet length and the return value from recv are consistent the very first call will do nothing (the erase is at but not past the end of the string).
 - There is something very wrong if the packet length and the return value from recv are not consistent. It might mean, for example, that multiple physical frames are needed to form a single logical frame, and that in turn means you need to go back to square one.
 - Suppose the physical and logical frames are one and the same, you're still going about this all wrong. As noted, the first time around you are erasing exactly nothing. That append at the start of the loop is exactly what you don't want to do.

Serialization oftentimes is a low-level concept and is best treated as such.

Comment: "Serialization oftentimes is a low-level concept and is best treated as such" +1 for that!

Comment: Rolled my own buffer. Better at C anyways

Comment: As far as mixing the binary data, you HAVE to, when your ethernet frames are 1500MTU (rougly 1452 bytes on the wire) big. So yes, thats WHY theres a binary header in the packet to begin with, to denote the end of the ascii payload and the start of the next binary payload. The real problems are this. Std::vector will not erase from the front of the array ( at least , im not STL wise enough to figure out how to make the damn thing to it without iteration out the arse on a packet thats almost 9k big.) , So, while a vector<char> would be seeming to be right

Comment: It's really NOT. Because on each sucesive call to receive, the sockets internal buffer has to be drained off a bit to make room for more data comming in on the wire.

Comment: Also, if your not familiar with the concept of needing a binariy header of some sort like struct Header{ unsigned short Feild1; unsigned short feild2; unsigned long Feild3;} then you kinda make me wonder about how much network code you've wrote :)

Comment: Also, The reason for the check on the end of The next "round " as you call it, its a very simple algorithm. The idea is, the very 1st packet you get, yes, clean slate, an append would put the index of the first bit of data at 0. all good. next time around , yea, maby the pacekt is less than the ethernet frame. 3rd or 4th around, the packets friggin 9k big. ethernet frame == 1452, packet == 9k. so.. IN that 9k , say the last frame isent quite 1452 big.

Comment: You have to keep the data at index 0 Right on the START of the binary header. So , you dump the data from the network on the end of your buffer (ie vector == good here, but really it's NOT) and proceed to chunk away at the packets in this huge GLOB of data you got to pray your whimpy regex can parse out. 1. You have to deal with the "Older than previous packets" Currently received when you dont get them on aligned sucessive calls to recv. Bravo btw, about the only thing you did get right, was the string class being junk for this purpose.

Comment: Btw, Keeping the data byte aligned at index 0 of the array , is the whole REASON for the reinterpret_cast , because static, and dynamic, dont guarantee byte alignment, reinterpret_cast does. The only tool in that code thats wrong, is a container from the STL. They have their place, with the way that network data flows a deque would conceptually be better,IF it wasen't for the fact that a deque doesnt garentee it's interal buffer to be byte aligned. ex idex postion 1 and 10 being exactly 9 bytes away from each other in a continuous string of ram, as one would need, for casting base data types.

Comment: You appear to be spending a lot of time justifying what appears to be a bad design. You came here for help. Why are you rejecting it? That you are getting fatal errors during execution is direct evidence that there is something seriously wrong with your design.

Comment: David. This is the last post im going to make in the comments to you. The design follows the data structure of the protocol i wrote that code for. The fact the STL doesn't have a FIFO buffer is not my concern. (as it's easy enough to implement on one's own.). And as far as a bad design. buddy, unless your a computer scientist,I wouldn't be calling tried and tested techniques bad design.